# xcode passing variables between views

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to get a string var from my delegate to current view as follows. However I am receiving a nil value. Thanks.

```
AppDelegate *theInstance = [AppDelegate alloc];

NSString *urlMain = [NSString alloc];

urlMain = [theInstance urlMain];
```

Comment: Try this lines `MyApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
Property *myProperty = appDelegate.property;`

Comment: great! working. Many thanks, please post it as answer

Comment: See the below answer; and i'm glad I helped you

Comment: I don't get you what do you mean by -1  coms for?? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this lines to access your app delegate

```
 MyApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 Property *myProperty = appDelegate.property;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not allocate an instance of your AppDelegate. You always have one AppDelegate instance while your application is running, and you can reach it with the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

A part from this, for getting the string you need you shouldn't do as you typed, but instead:

```
NSString *urlMail = [[appDelegate urlMain] copy];
```

if you really need a retained copy of that string.